# ArcGIS REST Server - Connection failed: Network error

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS v. 3.22.11 and am having issues connecting to ArcGIS
Server for some LiDAR data.  I get an error:

> Connection failed: Network error

Also when I hover with the cursor it says:

> Protocol "" is unknown

[image]

[image]

I searched and found a few other posts that were very similar but older.  I am quite new to all this so was not prepared to experiment with those answers without knowing the situation was a match.

Being new I may be going about this all wrong so the answer may be simple or perhaps someone with much more experience could try this link and see what the issue is as it may have nothing to do with QGIS.

Here is the URL link I am attempting to use :
https://maps.muskoka.on.ca/server/services/DEM/LiDAR_2018_DTM_Std/ImageServer

From this webpage:
https://map.muskoka.on.ca/datasets/00e5fa66c7804e029662b6af52360faa/about

Here is the screen shot of trying to add the URL as a Raster layer that I think @bixb0012 is suggesting ?
[image]

Comment: The answer likely lies in your error message, "Protocol '' is unknown."  For the URL, try putting an HTTPS:// in front of it, which will tell it to connect using that protocol.

Comment: Thank You @bixb0012.  I actually started out that way with the full URL as posted and got the same error.  As I understand it, you should be able to open a URL link such as that in your browser to see the coding but using Chrome all I get is a http.400: error.    Still digging for the answer.

Comment: If you get an HTTP error in your browser, then it has nothing to do with QGIS.  When I check the URL in my browser, I get an HTTP error as well, so either something is wrong on the server or the URL isn't valid.  I would reach out to the organization hosting the content.

Comment: I actually did talk to the people in the Muskoka GIS department and they said that the files are intended to be used by ESRI software users. Also I do not have a full AutoCAD licence they claim is an issue..  They also say the data is public but that seems to be a contradiction.  Is there a way to contact the ArcGIS server people or would that be a waste of time ?

Comment: I took a closer look, and I think it boils down to how the site is configured, specifically the ArcGIS REST Services Directory is disabled on the site to prevent browsing.  This can mess up some software that expects the site to be browse-able when making a connection.  Also, you are using a SOAP URL instead of a REST URL, so QGIS may be choking on that.  Have you tried using ArcGIS FeatureServer Layer to directly load the service as a layer?

Comment: I did try to use the "Data Source Manager " to load the URL service as a Raster layer if that is the same as you are suggesting ?  QGIS then gives me a warning of "Unsupported Data Source".

Comment: I just tested in QGIS.  You need to use the REST URL and not SOAP URL with the ArcGIS REST Servers connections.  The following URL works for me with the ArcGIS REST Severs connection:  `https://maps.muskoka.on.ca/server/rest/services/DEM/LiDAR_2018_DTM_Std/ImageServer`

Comment: Wonderful !  That seems to be working now and solves the error in QGIS.  Lots more to learn yet but this question is now resolved.  :)